# Correct way to finish transaction and than do some staff

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

In my project I need to do some updates in database and finish transaction. Then I need to call external application that should have access to result of current transaction (via other endpoints). currently I have just @Transactional annotation above of endpoint method.

Which is common way to deal with such situations?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ApplicationEventPublisher` to publish an event at the end of the `@Transactional` method.  Implement a `@TransactionalEventListener` method to handle this event which by default will only get called after the transaction commits successfully which means you don't need to worry about it will execute accidentally if the transaction fails.

Code wise , it looks like :

```java
@Service
public class MyServce {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher appEventPublisher;

    @Transactional
    public void doSomething(){

        Result result = doMyStuff();
        appEventPublisher.publishEvent(new StuffFinishedEvent(result));
    }
}

public class StuffFinishedEvent{

    private Result result;

    public StuffFinishedEvent(Result result){
        this.result = result;
    }
}
```

And the `@TransactionalEventListener` :

```java
@Component
public class FinishStuffHandler {

    @TransactionalEventListener(phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMMIT)
    public void handle(StuffFinishedEvent event) {   
        //access the result here.....
        event.getResult();
    }
}
```